# C++, как привязать действие на кнопку, библиотека fltk

Tags: c++

Перерыл всю документацию, но так и не понял. Как привязать действие на кнопку,например, выход. Например, есть кнопка exit(button). exit->callback(); как присвоить действие выход? Ещё,подскажите, пожалуйста, где есть подробная инструкция по данной библиотеке?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> как присвоить действие выход?

Как-то так:

```
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Button.H>
 
void do_exit(Fl_Widget *w) {
    w->top_window()->hide();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  Fl_Window *window = new Fl_Window(340,180);
  Fl_Button *btn = new Fl_Button(20,40,300,100,"Exit");
  btn->callback(do_exit);
  window->end();
  window->show(argc, argv);
  return Fl::run();
}
```

Или в стиле с++11:

```
btn->callback( [](Fl_Widget *w){
                 w->top_window()->hide();
               });
```

---

> где есть подробная инструкция по данной библиотеке?

Документация находится [здесь](https://www.fltk.org/doc-1.3/index.html).

Comment: Оба варианта подошли, спасибо!!!